# How to find different strings with extra word at the end in another string?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to check java string, against a glossary list and if it finds a term which exist in the glossary list then, wrap the term with an  tag. 
but the problem is that if I have two terms in the glossary list like :
"Sprint" and "Sprint 0" then the code only picks the Sprint term, and it ignores the "Sprint 0".

here is my code

```
    private String findGlassayTerms(String response, List<Glossary> glossary) {
    for (Glossary item : glossary) {
        // check if response contains the term
        if (StringUtils.contains(response, item.getTerm())) {
            System.out.println(item.getTerm());
            response = StringUtils.replace(response, item.getTerm(), "<span class=" + item.getTerm() + ">" + item.getTerm() + "</span>");

        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

here is the result :

```
<span class=Sprint>Sprint</span> 0 is typically a one or two week period at the end of the Define phase. <br>In summary, <span class=Sprint>Sprint</span> 0 provides an opportunity.
```

Comment: How about sorting the glossary from longest to shortest?

Comment: Well, you'd try and replace `Sprint 0` before `Sprint`, because the latter is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort your `List<Glossary> glossary` by term length (longest term first), your current code should work correctly. Another solution would be to build a list of all matches, and then loop through those to "score" the correct match. Next, I think you should rename your method to `findGlossaryTerms` (and not `findGlassayTerms`). Finally, that sort (in code) might be something like this -

```
Collections.sort(glossary, new Comparator<Glossary>() {
    public int compare(Glossary a, Glossary b) {
        if (a == null) {
            if (b == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        } else if (b == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        int av = (a.getTerm() != null) ? a.getTerm().length() : 0;
        int bv = (b.getTerm() != null) ? b.getTerm().length() : 0;
        return Integer.valueOf(bv).compareTo(av);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using your code, but I dont know why it is sorting from short to long, instead of sorting from long to short?

Comment: @user261002 Check the last line of the method, it should be `return Integer.valueOf(bv).compareTo(av);` I did edit it, so you may have the older version.