# avoid using a word for a second time in a search string

Tags: java, string, replace

I am trying to check java string, against a glossary list and if it finds a term which exist in the glossary list then, wrap the term with a html tag. 
I have already sorted the glossary from Longer to shorter to avoid the problem if finding the shorter term first then it can't find the longer term.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866011/how-to-find-different-strings-with-extra-word-at-the-end-in-another-string/22866203?noredirect=1). 
However, the problem is that now that if find all the terms, it cant avoid the second tag wrapping for the similar terms. for example if I have two terms : "Sprint" and "Sprint0" the result will be something like this:

```
    <span class="term"><span class="term">Sprint</span> 0</span> is typically a one or two week period at the end of the Define phase. 
<br>In summary, <span class="term"><span class="term">Sprint</span> 0</span> provides an opportunity for the team to:
<ul>
```

Here is the code:

> 

```
private String findGlossaryTerms(String response, List<Glossary> glossary) {
        for (Glossary item : glossary) {
            // check if response contains the term
            if (StringUtils.contains(response, item.getTerm())) {
                System.out.println(item.getTerm());
                response = StringUtils.replace(response, item.getTerm(), "<span class=\"term\">" + item.getTerm() + "</span>");

            }           
        }
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println("_____________________________");
        return response;
    }
```

How can I avoid this???

Comment: I think you should replace the call to `SringUtils.replace` with a regex find for a word. For example, use string's `matches` method to check against proper regex.

Comment: I have done this , but it is still the same.

Comment: It should be something like this `String reg = "\\b" + response + "\\b"; item.getTerm().matches(reg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

When you're replacing words in a string, and you don't want to replace the result of a previous replacement *again*, you cannot go over the entire string every time.
You can only go over the part of the string that you haven't replaced in yet.

Instead of searching the whole 'response' string for a replacement every time, you can go over each word in the string and see if it is in the glossary - if it is, you replace it with your HTML snippet. If it isn't, you leave it as is.

**Updated version of your method**

```
private static String findGlossaryTerms(String response, List<Glossary> glossary) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int offset = 0; offset < response.length(); offset++) {
        boolean match = false;
        for (Glossary item : glossary) {
            // check if the term is present at the current offset
            if (response.startsWith(item.getTerm(), offset)) {
                System.out.println(item.getTerm());
                builder.append("<span class=\"term\">").append(item.getTerm()).append("</span>");
                offset += item.getTerm().length() - 1;
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!match)
            builder.append(response.charAt(offset));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

**Driver / scaffolding code**

```
static class Glossary {

    private String term;

    public Glossary(String term) {
        this.term = term;
    }

    public String getTerm() {
        return term;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Glossary> glossary = new ArrayList<>();
    glossary.add(new Glossary("one or two"));
    glossary.add(new Glossary("Sprint0"));
    glossary.add(new Glossary("Sprint"));

    System.out.println(findGlossaryTerms("Sprint0 is typically a one or two week period at the end of the Define phase.", glossary));
}
```

**Output**

```
<span class="term">Sprint0</span> is typically a <span class="term">one or two</span> week period at the end of the Define phase.
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that there is a space between Spring and ), also, I have otehr terms like "Acceptance Criteria", that if I want to split the string then, it can find the words agains the actual glossary list

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. The principle still holds: you can't go over the same input twice while replacing, so you need to keep track where you were. In the code above I use `offset` for that and the code build the transformed string in the `StringBuilder result`. This version doesn't split in words but will try to match the glossary terms throughout the entire string. You still need to sort your terms longest-one-first as you did before.